# Difference between "другого ..., кроме как ..." and "другого ..., как ..."

Tags: грамматика

I just said in conversation:

> Похоже, у меня не остается **другого** выбора, **кроме как** помочь им.

I'm not sure if I could just as well have said "**другого** выбора, **как** помочь", dropping "кроме".

Comment: in Google there're twice as many phrases with *кроме* than without it (169,000 vs 82,000+), to me omission of *кроме* makes the phrase sound lacking

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although they are both possible, I disagree that they have the same meaning.

Expression **with кроме** discusses how you can't not help them -- *выбор* refers to the choice between helping and not helping, i.e. not helping is initially an option, but it's eventually rejected in favor of helping.

Expression **without кроме** discusses how there's no other way of helping them -- *выбор* refers to the choice between all the hypothetical ways to help them, i.e. not helping is not an option in the first place.

To sum up,

> Похоже, у меня не остается другого выбора, кроме как помочь им.

means

> Apparently, I have no choice but to help them.

On the other hand,

> Похоже, у меня не остается другого выбора, как помочь им.

means

> Apparently, I have no other option how to help them.

As mentioned by Баян in the comments, the last Russian sentence is a poor choice of words, and more natural way of saying would look like *...не остаётся другого способа помочь им*. Still, if you encountered *у меня не остаётся другого выбора, как помочь им*, and you totally can, you should definitely take it to mean "...I have no other option how to help them".

Comment: the sentence *Похоже, у меня не остается другого выбора, как помочь им* is worded poorly, in proper Russian this idea would be expressed as *не остаётся другого* ***способа*** *помочь им*

Comment: @БаянКупи-ка Agreed, but if it was encountered, it would definitely have this meaning and not the one where **кроме как** is used.

Comment: disagree about "definitely". Indeed, "как" alone might represent both cases, reduced "кроме как" and reduced "каким образом/способом"

Answer (score 0):

Both variants are grammatical and have the same meaning. 
The first variant is more explicit, and you can stick to it for that reason: there could be other similar phrases where *как* would rather mean *how*:

> я не знаю другого способа как тебе помочь.

(I do not know another way how to help you)